# how to check other two different function are true before submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My form submit code is below:

```js
function test_final(){
  //condition 1 & condition 2 are return true then only form submitted true otherwise return false
  test_one();
  test_two();
  }


function test_one{ //condition 1;
  var one = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if(one == "") {return false;}
  else{return true;}
  }
function test_two{//condition 2;
  var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if(two == "") {return false;}
  else{return true;}
  }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return test_final()" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="text" id="email">
  <button>submit</button>
```

In my above code check both two condition are satisfied then only form submitted  otherwise return false.but in this case its not working ..please correct my code or guide me on right way.Any help are appreciate..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function test_final(){
  //condition 1 & condition 2 are return true then only form submitted true otherwise return false
  return test_one() && test_two();
  
}


function test_one(){ 

  var one = document.getElementById('name').value;

  if(one == "") {
     return false;
  }
  else{
     return true;
  }
}

function test_two(){  //condition 2;
  
  var two = document.getElementById('email').value;

  if(two == "") {
     return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return test_final()" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="text" id="email">
  <button>submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: simple and superb..Thanks